# Live MySQL filtering via HTML Select

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to use a select list to actively filter the results I get from my SQL database. For example, if I choose "Yankees" from my select list, I want my SQL query to only show Yankee players.

EDIT: By "live filtering" I mean that when a user selects Yankees, Phillies, or Announcer, the select list will only display names under that category.

Here is my code for the select.

```
<select name="ident" id="ident">
    <option value="yankees">Yankees</option>
    <option value="phillies">Phillies</option>
    <option value="announcer">Announcer</option>
</select>
```

And this is the code that follows (after database connection):

```
<?php
    $ident = $_POST['ident'];
    $query = @mysql_query('SELECT name, id FROM grade ORDER BY name asc WHERE ident="' . $ident . '"');
    echo "<select name='name'>";
    while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<option>".htmlspecialchars($temp['name'])."</option>";
    }
        echo "</select>";
?>
```

I know the while statement works for populating my second select list (of names) if I manually put in the name, but am unsure if I can/am doing the live filtering of that list correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Not my question, but okay. Would you care to elaborate on this and  tell me what exactly is wrong?

Comment: A malicious user could POST invalid data that'd allow them to do any SQL query, including dropping your tables. You need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on `$ident` prior to using it in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you are not doing it correctly. First of all, there is a security hole. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Second, your SQL query was wrong. `ORDER BY` should have come after `WHERE` clause.

Here is the secure and correct way to do it:

```
<?php
$ident = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ident']);
$query = @mysql_query("SELECT name, id FROM grade WHERE ident = '$ident' ORDER BY name ASC");
echo "<select name='name'>";

while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<option>".htmlspecialchars($temp['name'])."</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Live filtering". Something like Google implemented in their search (which is called "Google Suggest")?

In this case, you would use JavaScript with the jQuery Library to update your list.

Also, you shouldn't use the `@` when you're testing something, because it suppresses the error message (if there is one) and you don't know what's wrong. If you don't want your productive server to give the user error-messages, there are options in the `php.ini`-file which disable this.

Last but not least, I would suggest you use a PreparedStatement to make prevent your code form SQL-Injections (this amuses you're using the MySQLi-class):

1. Create a PrearedStatement with the
   [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)-method.
2. [Bind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) your parameters
3. [Execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) the Statement
4. [Bind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) the results
5. [Fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) them.

Example code on this can be found in the linked PHPDoc-Samples.

Comment: In fact jquery isn't so necessary, and you can use error_reporting(0) (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: By live filtering I mean in one menu, a user could select Yankees, Phillies, or Announcer. In the second menu, the name results would be filtered by the name they just selected rather than having all Yankees, Phillies, and Announcer names listed.

Comment: @Tory If this should be done without reloading the Page, you'll need to do it with jQuery or something similar.